# Математическое выражение в Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

Всем доброго времени суток, есть запрос с выборкой с базы в таком виде:

```
select t1.nkl, t1.tzav, t1.Psum, t1.Lsum, t1.Ltl, t1.Lth, t1.nv, t1.nvp
from   zxp.valpr t1 
inner  join (
       select nkl, MAX(tzav) as maxi
       from   zxp.valpr
       where  tviv is null
       and    pvn = 0
       and    rop = 1
       group  by nkl
       ) t2
on     t1.nkl = t2.nkl 
and    t1.tzav = t2.maxi
where  1=1
and    t1.pvn = 0
and    t1.rop = 1
order  by t1.nkl
```

Мне нужно добавить мат. часть с выборкой с другой таблице, сделал следующим образом:

```
select nkl,tzav,Psum,Lsum,Ltl, Lth,nv,nvp,
       (1-Ltl/res_Ltl-Lth/res_Lth) resurs
from   (
         select t1.nkl, t1.tzav, t1.Psum, t1.Lsum, t1.Ltl, t1.Lth,
                t1.nv,t1.nvp,
                (select  L from zxp.valres where kl=t1.nkl and rop=0 and =1) res_Ltl,
                (select  L from zxp.valres where kl=t1.nkl and rop=0 and i=2) res_Lth
         from   zxp.valpr t1 
         inner  join (
                  select nkl, MAX(tzav) as maxi
                  from   zxp.valpr
                  where  tviv is null
                  and    pvn = 0
                  and    rop = 0
                  group  by nkl
                ) t2
         on     t1.nkl = t2.nkl 
         and    t1.tzav = t2.maxi
         where  1=1
         and    t1.pvn = 0
         and    t1.rop = 0
         order  by t1.nkl
)
```

Но что-то мне подсказывает что такой запрос не очень правильный, помогите с оптимизацией, и правильностью данного запроса, всем большое спасибо
Таблица с параметрами:

```
create table VALPR (
  nkl  NUMBER NOT NULL,
  TZAV DATE   NOT NULL,
  TVIV DATE   NOT NULL,
  PSUM NUMBER NOT NULL,
  LSUM NUMBER NOT NULL,
  LTL  NUMBER NOT NULL,
  LTH  NUMBER NOT NULL,
  NV   NUMBER NOT NULL,
  NVP  NUMBER NOT NULL);


create table VALRES(
  L   NUMBER NOT NULL,
  kl  NUMBER NOT NULL,
  rop NUMBER NOT NULL,
  i   NUMBER NOT NULL);

insert into VALPR values(1, to_date('01.01.16','dd.mm.yy'), to_date('03.01.16','dd.mm.yy'),2262, 138,84,54,128, 145)

insert into VALRES values(225, 1,0, 1)
insert into VALRES values(180, 1,0, 2)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если мне не изменяет память, у вас nkl может принимать только 4 значения. В таком случае оптимизация тут скорее экономия на спичках. Для оптимизации надо смотреть план выполнения на реальной базе. В теории один подзапрос в from лучше чем два в списке выборки, тогда можно сделать что то такое:

```
select nkl,tzav,Psum,Lsum,Ltl, Lth,nv,nvp,(1-Ltl/res_Ltl-Lth/res_Lth) resurs
  from (
    select t1.nkl, t1.tzav, t1.Psum, t1.Lsum, t1.Ltl, t1.Lth, t1.nv,t1.nvp,t3.res_Ltl,t3.res_Lth
      from zxp.valpr t1
      join (select nkl, MAX(tzav) as maxi from zxp.valpr
             where tviv is null and pvn = 0 and rop = 0
             group by nkl
           ) t2
        on t1.nkl = t2.nkl and t1.tzav = t2.maxi
      join (select kl,max(decode(i,1,L,NULL)) res_Ltl,max(decode(i,2,L,NULL)) res_Lth
              from zxp.valres where rop=0 and i between 1 and 2
              group by kl
           ) t3
         on t3.kl = t1.nkl
 where 1=1
   and t1.pvn = 0
   and t1.rop = 0
 )
order by nkl
```

А на счет "правильности" это вам виднее, если выбирает нужные данные - значит правильный :)

**UPD** Исходя из ваших предыдущих вопросов у вас tzav всегда максимален именно для записей с tviv=NULL и итоговый запрос выбирает именно их. в таком случае запрос можно еще упростить:

```
select nkl,tzav,Psum,Lsum,Ltl, Lth,nv,nvp,(1-Ltl/res_Ltl-Lth/res_Lth) resurs
  from (
    select t1.nkl, t1.tzav, t1.Psum, t1.Lsum, t1.Ltl, t1.Lth, t1.nv,t1.nvp,t3.res_Ltl,t3.res_Lth
      from
        (
         select v.*, MAX(tzav) over(partition by nkl) max_tzav
           from zxp.valpr v
          where tviv is null and pvn = 0 and rop = 0
        ) t1,
        (
         select kl,max(decode(i,1,L,NULL)) res_Ltl,max(decode(i,2,L,NULL)) res_Lth
           from zxp.valres where rop=0 and i between 1 and 2
           group by kl
        ) t3
 where t1.tzav = t1.max_tzav and t3.kl = t1.nkl
 )
order by nkl
```

В данном случае мы получаем максимальное значение tzav для каждого nkl оконной функцией `max() over()` прямо в строках данных, после чего во внешнем запросе условие `t1.tzav = t1.max_tzav` оставляет в выборке только строки с этим самым максимальным tzav. Таким образом мы избавляемся от отдельного подзапроса получающего максимумы. И join по моему громоздко выглядит, я его заменил на запятую с вынесением условия склейки из on в where. Но это скорее дело вкуса, оптимизатор Oracle запятую и join одинаково интерпретирует.

Comment: Данные выбирает, я просто только учусь поэтому и возникают такие вопросы ))) Большое вам спасибо :)

Comment: @Ethernets Посмотрите еще обновление. Оно как минимум красивее и оптимизатор говорит, что раза в полтора быстрее.